# a value of an infinite series, how to obtain this result

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm reading some books about series: convergence/divergence and methods of computing sums. Here is a problem stated by myself: what method allows to compute
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{8n+1}-\frac{1}{8n+3}\right)
$$
I know some series have nonelementary value, but this one has. The value can be written with known constants, as [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5B%281%2F%288n%2B1%29-1%2F%288n%2B3%29%29%2C%7Bn%2C0%2CInfinity%7D%5D) says.

The sum does not telescope. Also differentiating $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{8n+1}-\frac{1}{8n+3}\right)x^{8n+1 \text{ or } 3}$ gives nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{8n+1}-\frac{1}{8n+3}\right) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_0^1 x^{8n}-x^{8n+2}\,dx$$ $$=  \int_0^1 \sum_{n=0}^\infty\left( x^{8n}-x^{8n+2}\right)\,dx =\int_0^1\frac{1-x^2}{1-x^8}\,dx$$

From here you can use standard integration methods.

Answer (score 1):

It is always interesting to work with the partial sums (at least to me).

Using the formula given by Wolfram Alpha
$$S_k=\sum_{n=0}^{k}\left(\frac{1}{8n+1}-\frac{1}{8n+3}\right)=$$
$$\frac{1}{8} \left(\psi \left(k+\frac{9}{8}\right)-\psi
   \left(k+\frac{11}{8}\right)+\psi \left(\frac{3}{8}\right)-\psi
   \left(\frac{1}{8}\right)\right)=$$
$$\frac{\pi +2 \sqrt{2} \coth ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2}\right)}{8} +\frac{1}{8} \left(\psi ^{(0)}\left(k+\frac{9}{8}\right)-\psi
   ^{(0)}\left(k+\frac{11}{8}\right)\right) $$ and using the asymptotics of the digamma function
$$S_k=\frac{\pi +2 \sqrt{2} \coth ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2}\right)}{8}-\frac{1}{32 k}+\frac{3}{128 k^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^3}\right)$$